# How to get location of %temp%\Low when running as a low intergrity process

Tags: windows, windows-7, windows-vista, uac

When a process is running at the low integrity level, you can't write to %temp% so I need a way to find the path to the %temp%\Low directory (Without hardcoding the word "Low")

Answer (score 5):

The ["Finding Low Integrity Write Locations" section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250462%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#wpm_fliwl) of the "Understanding and Working in Protected Mode Internet Explorer" article includes the following tidbit:

> **Note** Protected Mode modifies IE's environment variables. As a result, the GetTempPath() function returns %Temp%\Low when called while Protected Mode is active.

Comment: I don't think this is true. `GetTempPath` returns `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Temp\` for low integrity process in my case.

Answer (score 3):

According to  [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250462%28VS.85%29.aspx)

> When in Protected Mode, extensions can
>   write files to a folder below the
>   user's UserProfile folder, typically
>   %userprofile%\AppData\LocalLow. Use
>   the SHGetKnownFolderPath function with
>   the FOLDERID_LocalAppDataLow flag to
>   obtain the expanded folder name.

```
SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_LocalAppDataLow, 0, 
   NULL, szPath, ARRAYSIZE(szPath));
```

Comment: While this isn't a direct answer to your question, it seems to be the only safe folder you can get without hardcoding the path. I'd use that and create the temp folder there. (Of course this puts more responsibility on you to manage the eventual deletion of the files).

Comment: FOLDERID_LocalAppDataLow + "Temp\" seems to work and it is the correct path, while I really don't like the hard-coded "Temp".

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking for a temporary directory to write to, you could loop through the directories inside the `%temp%` directory and try to write to each.

If UAC is disabled, `.` should be the first. If not, `.\Low` should be the only one.

Comment: It's interesting, maybe the OS takes care to give you the Temp\Low path in the %temp% environemnt variable, so GetTempPath() returns the correct path? I didn't test it. However, this does *not* correlate directly to UAC. UAC keeps you from always running with a high-integrity token - But even when UAC is disabled, processes can be created with low integrity.

Answer (score -1):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb625960.aspx)

"Low-integrity processes can write and create subfolders under %USER PROFILE%\AppData\LocalLow"

I don't think there's any way to avoid hardcoding thost last two folders.